# UML diagram collection of objects

Tags: class, oop, object, collections, uml

I need to design a UML class diagram but I have the following problem. The application I am designing consists of a set of objects, let's say cars. What I want to do, is keep a record of all the cars, the days they've been used, etc.. So, I have a car class. Should I have also a CarCollection class? If yes, how should I implement it?

I should keep in mind that I'm not modelling a database.

Thank's!

Comment: I'm afraid there is no definite answer to that. It strongly depends on the business you model. On some level you probably might need some sort of Registry but if it's not critical, you shouldn't put it on a model (especially f all your cars pose that Registry). Instead show those classes that are related to your cars from a business perspective (so from your description CarUsage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's homework:

> I need to design a UML [class diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html) (...). 
>   I should keep in mind that (...)

I'll help you but won't do the work for you.  From your narrative, you can deduce the following:

- a [class](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class.html) `Car`
- a class `Usage` (with property `date_of_use`)
- [association](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html?context=class-diagrams) of 1 `Car` with n `Usage`

This diagram shows the classes of a system that manages one set of cars composed of all the objects of that class.  There is no need for an additional collection.

But you could of course add a class `Fleet`, with an [aggregation](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html?context=class-diagrams) of `Cars`.  Then your system could manage several independent sets of cars : it would comply with the narrative as well, because it could be used to manage the special case of a single set as well.